# Overriding default assets renderer in Magento2

Tags: magento2

There is a `getAssetTemplate` function in `magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Config/Renderer.php`.

I want to override it to make render things in a bit different way.

I don't want to update these files from vendor directory. What would be the proper way to make changes to this function?

The general question is what is the way to override classes under `vendor/magento/framework`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using `Preference`
Just simply add this line to your **`di.xml`** file of your custom module.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php" type="vendor\module\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php" />

</config>
```

`vendor\module\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php` is your class that extends `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php`, through it you can make whatever changes you want.

Note: change **`vendor\module`** according to your real custom module